# Find the following Double Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> $\int\int_D\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2y})$ while $D=\{(x,y): y\ge x, y\ge \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, y\le\sqrt[3]{x} \}$.

To start off, I drew these functions: $y=x, y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, y=\sqrt[3]{x}$. 
And I can see that $y=\sqrt[3]{x},y=x$ intersect at $1$. 
now I need to check when $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ intersect to decide my $x$ borders: 
$\sqrt[3]{x}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \Longrightarrow x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$. 

Now I'm not really sure how to continue, if I take borders of $y$ then I'll be just calculating a volume of a box or something. 
So I decided to find borders of $y$, since there's one function from above ($y=x$) and one under ($y=\sqrt[3]{x}$). 
So now $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\le y\le 1$. so my integral will be : 
$\int^1_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}dy \int^x_{\sqrt[3]{x}}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{2y}) dx$.

I feel like I have made some mistakes reaching this, I would appreciate any help and feedback about how to find this integral, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but you need to write bounds of $x$ in terms of $y$. See the region you are to integrate over -

[image]

So if we integrate over $dx$ first, we can do it in one integral -

$ \displaystyle \int^1_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} \left[ \int^y_{y^3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{2y}\right) \ dx \right] dy$

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, got an extra question if possible, if I wanted to do it while we go over $x$ (the first approach I tried), I could do it from $1$ to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ with $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ above and $y=x$ under, and then from $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ to intersection of $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ while  $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$ being the upper function?

Comment: Yes you need two integrals then. Here is the problem though - see the $\sin$ function. $y$ is in the denominator so integrating it wrt $y$ first is going to be more complicated, right?

Comment: and any further questions related to this, please feel free to ping.

Comment: Does it make any sense that I'm getting $-\frac{1}{4\pi}$ as an answer? can a double integral be negative? or did I probably make a mistake?

Comment: Oops I have made a mistake and wrote $y$ instead of $2y$, got an answer of $\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}$

Comment: Something still wrong. You should get $\pi^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: Oh yes I missed $\frac{1}{\pi}$ on the way, got the same answer with $\pi^2$ now, thanks alot for all your help! really appreciate it